# How disable outlook meeting notifications

Tags: outlook, calendar

There I have an issue hope so I will get the right answer here. I have an real estate business. I am using the outlook calendar to book the meetings. but when I am assigning the time to the user or doing any edit-related operation that time another user is getting the mail alerts.i want to disable those I only want to send those the appointment mail noting else. is there any way to disable those emails?

Answer (score 0):

The [Application.ItemSend](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.application.itemsend) event is fired whenever an Microsoft Outlook item is sent, either by the user through an Inspector (before the inspector is closed, but after the user clicks the Send button) or when the `Send` method for an Outlook item, such as MailItem, is used in a program. So, if you need to prevent anything from sending out, you can set the `Cancel` parameter to false, for example, a VBA handler is shown below:

```
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean) 
 Dim prompt As String 
 prompt = "Are you sure you want to send " & Item.Subject & "?" 
 If MsgBox(prompt, vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "Sample") = vbNo Then 
   Cancel = True 
 End If
End Sub
```